# How can I access nginx ingress on my local?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, nginx-ingress, docker-desktop

I can't connect to my app running with nginx ingress (Docker Desktop win 10).

The nginx-ingress controller pod is running, the app is healthy, and I have created an ingress. However, when I try to connect to my app on localhost, I get "connection refused".

I see this error in the log:

```
[14:13:13.028][VpnKit            ][Info   ] vpnkit.exe: Connected Ethernet interface f6:16:36:bc:f9:c6

[14:13:13.028][VpnKit            ][Info   ] vpnkit.exe: UDP interface connected on 10.96.181.150

[14:13:22.320][GoBackendProcess  ][Info   ] Adding vpnkit-k8s-controller tcp forward from 0.0.0.0:80 to 10.96.47.183:80
[14:13:22.323][ApiProxy          ][Error  ] time="2019-12-09T14:13:22-05:00" msg="Port 443 for service ingress-nginx is already opened by another service"
```

I think port 443 is used by another app, possibly zscaler security or skype.
Excerpt from `netstat -a -b`:

```
 [svchost.exe]
  TCP    0.0.0.0:443            0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       16012
 [com.docker.backend.exe]
  TCP    0.0.0.0:443            0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       8220
```

I don't know how to make the ingress work. Please help!

My ingress:

```
$ kubectl describe ing kbvalues-deployment-dev-ingress
Name:             kbvalues-deployment-dev-ingress
Namespace:        default
Address:          localhost
Default backend:  default-http-backend:80 (<none>)
Rules:
  Host       Path  Backends
  ----       ----  --------
  localhost
             /   kbvalues-deployment-dev-frontend:28000 (10.1.0.174:8080)
Annotations:
  kubernetes.io/ingress.class:                     nginx
  nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-headers:  X-Forwarded-For, X-app123-XPTO
Events:
  Type    Reason  Age               From                      Message
  ----    ------  ----              ----                      -------
  Normal  CREATE  42m               nginx-ingress-controller  Ingress default/kbvalues-deployment-dev-ingress
  Normal  UPDATE  6s (x5 over 42m)  nginx-ingress-controller  Ingress default/kbvalues-deployment-dev-ingress
```

My service:

```
$ kubectl describe svc kbvalues-deployment-dev-frontend
Name:              kbvalues-deployment-dev-frontend
Namespace:         default
Labels:            chart=tomcat-sidecar-war-1.0.4
                   environment=dev
                   name=kbvalues-frontend-dev
                   release=kbvalues-test
                   tier=frontend
Annotations:       <none>
Selector:          app=kbvalues-dev
Type:              ClusterIP
IP:                10.98.89.94
Port:              <unset>  28000/TCP
TargetPort:        8080/TCP
Endpoints:         10.1.0.174:8080
Session Affinity:  None
Events:            <none>
```

I am trying to access the app at: `http://localhost:28000/health`. I verified that the `/health` URL is accessible locally within the web server container.

I appreciate any help you can offer.

**Edit:**

I tried altering the ingress-nginx service to remove HTTPS, as suggested here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/56303330/166850

This got rid of the 443 error in the logs, but didn't fix my setup (still getting connection refused).

**Edit 2:** Here is the Ingress YAML definition (kubectl get -o yaml):

```
$ kubectl get ing -o yaml
apiVersion: v1
items:
- apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
  kind: Ingress
  metadata:
    annotations:
      kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    creationTimestamp: "2019-12-09T18:47:33Z"
    generation: 5
    name: kbvalues-deployment-dev-ingress
    namespace: default
    resourceVersion: "20414"
    selfLink: /apis/extensions/v1beta1/namespaces/default/ingresses/kbvalues-deployment-dev-ingress
    uid: 5c34bf7f-1ab4-11ea-80e4-00155d169409
  spec:
    rules:
    - host: localhost
      http:
        paths:
        - backend:
            serviceName: kbvalues-deployment-dev-frontend
            servicePort: 28000
          path: /
  status:
    loadBalancer:
      ingress:
      - hostname: localhost
kind: List
metadata:
  resourceVersion: ""
  selfLink: ""
```

**Edit 3:** Output of `kubectl get svc -A` (ingress line only):

```
ingress-nginx   ingress-nginx                      LoadBalancer   10.96.47.183     localhost     80:30470/TCP             21h
```

**Edit 4:** I tried to get the VM's IP address from windows HyperV, but it seems like the VM doesn't have an IP?

```
PS C:\> (Get-VMNetworkAdapter -VMName DockerDesktopVM)

Name            IsManagementOs VMName          SwitchName MacAddress   Status IPAddresses
----            -------------- ------          ---------- ----------   ------ -----------
Network Adapter False          DockerDesktopVM DockerNAT  00155D169409 {Ok}   {}
```

**Edit 5:**

Output of `netstat -a -n -o -b` for port 80:

```
  TCP    0.0.0.0:80             0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       4
 Can not obtain ownership information
```

Comment: Are you able to access the service without Ingress? Like directly hitting the service IP and port works?

Comment: You should try doing `kubectl exec -it <your nginx pod> /bin/bash`, run the curl command for what Shubham suggested and check your outputs.

Comment: What's the output of `kubectl get svc -A` (only pasting the ingress line)? I suspect your ingress service is not configured correctly. For cloud environments, i'd expect the Type to be `LoadBalancer` however for your case, I think you may need to configure it to use `NodePort` where you'd access your ingress using a port (E.g., https://localhost:30252/myapp).

Comment: @Shubham @randominstanceOfLivingThing I was able to access the service successfully using: ```kubectl port-forward svc/kbvalues-deployment-dev-frontend 28000``` and hitting: ```http://localhost:28000/health```

Comment: @RMorrisey if your comment solved your problem please provide an answer to your post and accept it for future reference.

Comment: @DawidKruk Sorry for the confusion - my problem is still unsolved. The above command is only a workaround; it doesn't fix the ingress functionality as described in the OP.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Enable Ingress controller on Docker Desktop with WLS2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65193758/enable-ingress-controller-on-docker-desktop-with-wls2)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I have managed to create Ingress resource in Kubernetes on Docker in Windows.

**Steps to reproduce**:

- Enable Hyper-V
- Install Docker for Windows and enable Kubernetes
- Connect kubectl
- Enable Ingress
- Create deployment
- Create service
- Create ingress resource
- Add host into local hosts file
- Test

#### Enable [Hyper-V](https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/quick-start/enable-hyper-v)

From Powershell with administrator access run below command:

`Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName  Microsoft-Hyper-V -All`

System could ask you to reboot your machine.

#### Install Docker for Windows and enable Kubernetes

Install Docker application with all the default options and enable Kubernetes

#### Connect kubectl

Install [kubectl](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-kubectl/#install-kubectl-on-windows) .

#### Enable Ingress

Run this commands:

```
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/master/deploy/static/mandatory.yaml
```

```
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/master/deploy/static/provider/cloud-generic.yaml
```

#### **Edit:** Make sure no other service is using port 80

Restart your machine. From a `cmd` prompt running as admin, do:
`net stop http`
Stop the listed services using `services.msc`

Use: `netstat -a -n -o -b` and check for other processes listening on port 80.

#### Create deployment

Below is simple deployment with pods that will reply to requests:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: hello
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: hello
      version: 2.0.0
  replicas: 3
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: hello
        version: 2.0.0
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: hello
        image: "gcr.io/google-samples/hello-app:2.0"
        env:
        - name: "PORT"
          value: "50001"
```

Apply it by running command:

`$ kubectl apply -f file_name.yaml`

#### Create service

For pods to be able for you to communicate with them you need to create a service.

Example below:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: hello-service
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: hello
    version: 2.0.0
  ports:
  - name: http
    protocol: TCP
    port: 80
    targetPort: 50001
```

Apply this service definition by running command:

`$ kubectl apply -f file_name.yaml`

#### Create Ingress resource

Below is simple Ingress resource using service created above:

```yaml
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: hello-ingress 
spec:
  rules:
  - host: hello-test.internal
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: hello-service 
          servicePort: http
```

Take a look at:

```yaml
spec:
  rules:
  - host: hello-test.internal
```

`hello-test.internal`  will be used as the `hostname` to connect to your pods.

Apply your Ingress resource by invoking command:

`$ kubectl apply -f file_name.yaml`

#### Add host into local hosts file

I found this [Github link](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/1901)  that will allow you to connect to your Ingress resource by `hostname`.

To achieve that add a line `127.0.0.1 hello-test.internal` to your `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` file and save it.
You will need Administrator privileges to do that.

**Edit:** The newest version of Docker Desktop for Windows already adds a hosts file entry:
`127.0.0.1 kubernetes.docker.internal`

#### Test

Display the information about Ingress resources by invoking command:
`kubectl get ingress`

It should show:

```
NAME            HOSTS                 ADDRESS     PORTS   AGE
hello-ingress   hello-test.internal   localhost   80      6m2s
```

Now you can access your Ingress resource by opening your web browser and typing

`http://kubernetes.docker.internal/`

The browser should output:

```
Hello, world!
Version: 2.0.0
Hostname: hello-84d554cbdf-2lr76
```

`Hostname: hello-84d554cbdf-2lr76` is the name of the pod that replied.

If this solution is not working please check connections with the command:
`netstat -a -n -o` 
(**with Administrator privileges**) if something is not using port 80.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed writeup! I will try following these steps tomorrow morning and report back

Comment: Sorry! I got used to working around it with kubectl proxy and forgot! I'll try it right now.

Comment: Following the steps above broke my kubectl context. It now says: ``` kubectl get ing
Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp: lookup kubernetes.docker.internal: no such host```

Comment: Let me find where kubernetes.docker.internal is set

Comment: I changed the cluster settings in my .kube config file, but now I get: ```Unable to connect to the server: x509: certificate is valid for docker-for-desktop, kubernetes, kubernetes.default, kubernetes.default.svc, kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local, kubernetes.docker.internal, vm.docker.internal, localhost, not hello-test.internal
```

Comment: Trying to change everything from hello-test.internal to kubernetes.docker.internal

Comment: I tried the following changes:
-Changed cluster config back to how it was
-Changed hosts to say: 127.0.0.1 kubernetes.docker.internal
-Changed ingress rule to:   - host: kubernetes.docker.internal

Comment: Now I am able to use kubectl once again, but I got a 404 error page from the web server accessing:
```http://kubernetes.docker.internal/```

Comment: ```kubectl get ing``` shows:
hello-ingress   kubernetes.docker.internal   localhost   80      5m14s

Comment: I scaled back the deployment to one pod for debugging, retried my test request, and checked the logs. There is no record of my HTTP request:
2019/12/18 19:36:17 Server listening on port 50001

Comment: To be clear, all of the steps above worked up until the hosts file step - that's what broke my kubectl

Comment: The hosts file had an entry: ```127.0.0.1 kubernetes.docker.internal``` I changed this entry to hello-test.internal and that broke it.

Comment: I tried a couple different variations (having both entries:
127.0.0.1 kubernetes.docker.internal
127.0.0.1 hello-test.internal)
(having both items in the same line: 127.0.0.1 kubernetes.docker.internal hello-test.internal). In both fo these configs, kubectl was working but I still got the 404.

Comment: Netstat -a -n -o -b says "Can not obtain ownership information" for port 80

Comment: The 404 page has the following label: "openresty/1.15.8.2"

Comment: Restarted my PC, and stopped several services using `net stop http`. The HTTP service will not stop, but I got to the point where I get "connection refused" when accessing localhost:80. Started up docker desktop and started kubernetes local cluster. Now I am back to the 404 page (from openresty).

Comment: I got it working! Thanks so much!
The solution was:

Comment: 1) Restart my PC and stop all services using HTTP (use 'net stop http' to find out which ones)

Comment: 2) Start up docker desktop & kubernetes

Comment: 3) Change hosts file and ingress to use kubernetes.docker.internal

Comment: 4) Fix sample service & ingress given above so that they map to port 80 (ingress ->           servicePort: http) (service ->   ports:
  - name: http
    protocol: TCP
    port: 80
    targetPort: 50001)

Comment: i was facing similar issue while deploying ingress-nginx controller using the manual steps mentioned for bareMetal node at (https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/) however was facing an issue , however referred to the link (https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/1901)  mentioned by RMorrisey which mentioned to install ingress-nginx using the steps mentioned for mac and it worked without making cny changes to host file , etc

Comment: Thank you, I spent hours to figure it out what the problem was, all I had to do is use http://kubernetes.docker.internal/ URL, that you wrote in the last section. This should be in the docs on this page https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/ but there is no Docker Desktop for Windows section there :(

Comment: Little bit of update to my previous comment.
I "reinstalled" all k8s related stuff to write down step-by-step what needs to be done to run my pods. So to use the http://kubernetes.docker.internal URL in Docker Desktop for WINDOWS you need to install this ingress controller too: https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/#docker-for-mac
Yes, you need that, the Docker for Mac version, it works perfectly today on Windows, Docker Desktop 2.5.0.1 (49550)

Comment: I am using win 10 home where hyper v is not there. So what should I do ?

Comment: @yogihosting I have no access to a Windows 10 Home machine but I'd reckon you can use Docker Desktop with `wsl2` backend. Also you can look for other solutions like `minikube` with `virtualbox` driver. The setup for accessing ingress on your localhost machine will be slightly different but it will be also possible.

Comment: TLDR: add ingress class!

I kept getting a 404 from NGINX. I looked into the ingress controller pod logs using `kubectl logs -n ingress-nginx pod/ingress-nginx-controller-***pod-hash-here***` and found this error message: `Ignoring ingress because of error while validating ingress class" ingress="mongo-ns/mongo-ingress" error="ingress does not contain a valid IngressClass`. Turns out, I needed to add this under metadata/annotations:      `kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx`

Answer (score 2):

On Windows the Kubernetes cluster is running in a VM. Try to access ingress on that VM-s IP address instead of `localhost`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. How can I find out the IP of the VM?

Comment: With minikube, I could use ```minikube ip```, but Docker Desktop seems to work differently... not sure how to get it.

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to get the IP from HyperV. It looks like the VM doesn't have an IP assigned?

Comment: Hold on. I'm trying to setup Kubernetes with Docker on Windows 10, then I'll dig more deep.

Comment: Unfortunately I was not able to set it up. Tried on two machines. [Same errors](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/1962). Can you try to list `kubectl get nodes` and `kubectl describe node` and post the output?

Comment: Maybe it would be better to use `minikube`.

Comment: Minikube is problematic in my environment because it doesn't use windows native networking. It has trouble with zscaler and with our VPN.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access the ingress on localhost without any special host names, it's enough if you enable the ingress nginx controller:

kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/main/deploy/static/provider/kind/deploy.yaml

You don't even need to specify the `-host` argument in your Ingress.
If you have a special host name, such as my-test.com, you have to add the domain the the `/etc/hosts` file as the others mentioned.

I hope it helps somebody!

Answer (score 0):

i was facing similar issue while deploying ingress-nginx controller using the manual steps mentioned for bareMetal node at [ingress-nginx-deploy](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/) however was facing an issue , however referred to the link [Github link](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/1901)  mentioned by @RMorrisey which leads to other threads where they have mentioned to install ingress-nginx using the steps mentioned for mac and it worked without making cny changes to host file , etc

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your service has a type of ClusterIP, which isn't accessible externally. You need it to be of type NodePort, which is what is done in Dawid Kruk's instructions.