# kubectl cannot acces pod application

Tags: mysql, wordpress, kubernetes

A have this pod specification :

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: wp
spec:
  containers:
  - image: wordpress:4.9-apache
    name: wordpress
    env:
      - name: WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD
        value: mysqlpwd
      - name: WORDPRESS_DB_HOST
        value: 127.0.0.1
  - image: mysql:5.7
    name: mysql
    env:
    - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
      value: mysqlpwd
    volumeMounts:
    - name: data
      mountPath: /var/lib/mysql
  volumes:
    - name: data
      emptyDir: {}
```

I deployed it using :

> kubectl create -f wordpress-pod.yaml

Now it is correctly deployed :

> kubectl get pods 
>   wp     2/2     Running   3          35h

Then when i do :

> kubectl describe po/wp

```
Name:         wp
Namespace:    default
Priority:     0
Node:         node3/192.168.50.12
Start Time:   Mon, 13 Jan 2020 23:27:16 +0100
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  <none>
Status:       Running
IP:           10.233.92.7
IPs:
  IP:  10.233.92.7
Containers:
```

My issue is that i cannot access to the app :

```
wget http://192.168.50.12:8080/wp-admin/install.php
Connecting to 192.168.50.12:8080... failed: Connection refused.
```

Neither wget http://10.233.92.7:8080/wp-admin/install.php 
works

Is there any issue in the pod description or deployment process ?

Thanks

Comment: Is this cluster cloud provided? Is it a minikube environment?

Answer (score 2):

With your current setup you need to use `wget http://10.233.92.7:8080/wp-admin/install.php` from within the cluster i.e by performing `kubectl exec` into another pod because `10.233.92.7` IP is valid only within the cluster.

You should create a [service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/) for exposing your pod. Create a cluster IP type service(default) for accessing from within the cluster. If you want to access from outside the cluster i.e from your desktop then create a NodePort or LoadBalancer type service.

Other way to access the application from your desktop will be [port forwarding](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/port-forward-access-application-cluster/). In this case you don't need to create a service.

Here is a tutorial for [accessing pods using NodePort service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/service-access-application-cluster/). In this case your node need to have public ip.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your configuration is lack of services that will allow external access to your `WordPress`.

There a lot of materials explaining what are the options and how they are strictly connected with infrastructure that Kubernetes works on.

Let me elaborate on 3 of them:

- minikube
- kubeadm
- cloud provisioned (GKE, EKS, AKS)

**The base of the `WordPress` configuration will be the same in each case.**

### Table of contents:

- Running MySQL

  - Secret
  - PersistentVolumeClaim
  - Deployment
  - Service
- Running WordPress

  - PersistentVolumeClaim
  - Deployment
- Allowing external access

  - minikube
  - kubeadm
  - cloud provisioned (GKE)

There is a good tutorial on Kubernetes site: [HERE!](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/stateful-application/mysql-wordpress-persistent-volume/)

### Running MySQL

#### Secret

As the official Kubernetes documentation:

> Kubernetes `secret` objects let you store and manage sensitive information, such as passwords, OAuth tokens, and ssh keys. Putting this information in a `secret` is safer and more flexible than putting it verbatim in a [Pod](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-overview/) definition or in a [container image](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/glossary/?all=true#term-image).
>
> -- [Kubernetes secrets](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/)

Example below is a `YAML` definition of a secret used for `MySQL` password:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: mysql-password
type: Opaque
data:
  password: c3VwZXJoYXJkcGFzc3dvcmQK
```

Take a specific look at:

```
  password: c3VwZXJoYXJkcGFzc3dvcmQK
```

**This password is base64 encoded**.

To create this password invoke command from your terminal:
`$ echo "YOUR_PASSWORD" | base64`

Paste the output to the `YAML` definition and apply it with:
`$ kubectl apply -f FILE_NAME`.

You can check if it was created correctly with: 
`$ kubectl get secret mysql-password -o yaml`

#### PersistentVolumeClaim

MySQL require a dedicated space for storing the data. There is an official documentation explaining it: [Persistent Volumes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/)

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: mysql-pv-claim
  labels:
    app: wordpress
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 2Gi
```

Above `YAML` will create a storage claim for `MySQL`. Apply it with command:

`$ kubectl apply -f FILE_NAME`.

#### Deployment

Create a `YAML` definition of a deployment from the official example and adjust it if there were any changes to names of the objects:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1 # for versions before 1.9.0 use apps/v1beta2
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: wordpress-mysql
  labels:
    app: wordpress
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: wordpress
      tier: mysql
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: wordpress
        tier: mysql
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: mysql:5.6
        name: mysql
        env:
        - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: mysql-password
              key: password
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3306
          name: mysql
        volumeMounts:
        - name: mysql-persistent-storage
          mountPath: /var/lib/mysql
      volumes:
      - name: mysql-persistent-storage
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: mysql-pv-claim
```

Take a specific look on the part below, which is parsing `secret` password to the `MySQL` pod:

```
        - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: mysql-password
              key: password
```

Apply it with command: `$ kubectl apply -f FILE_NAME`.

#### Service

What was missing in your the configuration was service objects. This objects allows communication with other pods, external traffic etc. Look at below example:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: wordpress-mysql
  labels:
    app: wordpress
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 3306
  selector:
    app: wordpress
    tier: mysql
  clusterIP: None
```

This definition will create a object which will point to the `MySQL` pod.

It will create a DNS entry with the name of `wordpress-mysql` and IP address of the pod.

It will not expose it to external traffic as it's not needed.

Apply it with command: `$ kubectl apply -f FILE_NAME`.

### Running WordPress

#### Persistent Volume Claim

As well as `MySQL`, `WordPress` require a dedicated space for storing the data. Create it with below example:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: wp-pv-claim
  labels:
    app: wordpress
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 2Gi
```

Apply it with command: `$ kubectl apply -f FILE_NAME`.

#### Deployment

Create `YAML` definition of `WordPress` as example below:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1 # for versions before 1.9.0 use apps/v1beta2
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: wordpress
  labels:
    app: wordpress
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: wordpress
      tier: frontend
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: wordpress
        tier: frontend
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: wordpress:4.8-apache
        name: wordpress
        env:
        - name: WORDPRESS_DB_HOST
          value: wordpress-mysql
        - name: WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: mysql-password
              key: password
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
          name: wordpress
        volumeMounts:
        - name: wordpress-persistent-storage
          mountPath: /var/www/html
      volumes:
      - name: wordpress-persistent-storage
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: wp-pv-claim
```

Take a specific look at:

```
        - name: WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: mysql-password
              key: password
```

This part will parse secret value to the deployment.

Below definition will tell `WordPress` where `MySQL` is located:

```
        - name: WORDPRESS_DB_HOST
          value: wordpress-mysql
```

Apply it with command: `$ kubectl apply -f FILE_NAME`.

### Allowing external access

There are many different approaches for configuring external access to applications.

#### Minikube

**Configuration could differ between different hypervisors.**

For example `Minikube` can expose `WordPress` to external traffic with:

#### NodePort

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: wordpress-nodeport 
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
      app: wordpress
      tier: frontend
  ports:
  - name: wordpress-port
    protocol: TCP
    port: 80
    targetPort: 80
```

After applying this definition you will need to enter the `minikube` IP address with appropriate port to the web browser.

This port can be found with command:
`$ kubectl get svc wordpress-nodeport`

Output of above command:

```sh
wordpress-nodeport   NodePort   10.76.9.15   <none>        80:30173/TCP   8s
```

In this case it is `30173`.

#### LoadBalancer

[In this case it will create NodePort also!](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/384#issuecomment-234409957)

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: wordpress-loadbalancer
  labels:
    app: wordpress
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 80
  selector:
    app: wordpress
    tier: frontend
  type: LoadBalancer
```

#### Ingress resource

Please refer to this link: [Minikube: create-an-ingress-resource](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/achttps://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/ingress-minikube/#cess-application-cluster/ingress-minikube/#create-an-ingress-resource)

Also you can refer to this [Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59255445/how-can-i-access-nginx-ingress-on-my-local/59274163#59274163)

### Kubeadm

With the Kubernetes clusters provided by `kubeadm` there are:

#### NodePort

The configuration process is the same as in `minikube`. The only difference is that it will create `NodePort` on each of every node in the cluster. After that you can enter IP address of any of the node with appropriate port. Be aware that you will neeed to be in the same network without firewall blocking your access.

#### LoadBalancer

You can create `LoadBalancer`  object with the same `YAML` definition as in `minikube`. The problem is that with `kubeadm` provisioning on a bare metal cluster the `LoadBalancer` will not get IP address.  The one of the options is: [MetalLB](https://metallb.universe.tf/)

#### Ingress

Ingress resources share the same problem as `LoadBalancer` in `kubeadm` provisioned infrastructure. As above one of the options is: [MetalLB](https://metallb.universe.tf/).

### Cloud Provisioned

There are many options which are strictly related to cloud that Kubernetes works on. Below is example for configuring `Ingress` resource with NGINX controller on GKE:

Apply both of the `YAML` definitions:

```
$ kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/nginx-0.27.1/deploy/static/mandatory.yaml
```

```
$ kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/nginx-0.27.1/deploy/static/provider/cloud-generic.yaml
```

**Apply `NodePort` definition from `minikube`**

Create Ingress resource:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: wordpress-nodeport
          servicePort: wordpress-port
```

Apply it with command: `$ kubectl apply -f FILE_NAME`.

Check if `Ingress` resource got the address from cloud provider with command:

`$ kubectl get ingress`

The output should look like that:

```sh
NAME      HOSTS   ADDRESS         PORTS   AGE
ingress   *       XXX.XXX.XXX.X   80      26m
```

After entering the IP address from above command you should get: 
[image: WordPress web browser first use]

Cloud provisioned example can be used for `kubeadm` provisioned clusters with the `MetalLB` configured.