# Docker Desktop + k8s plus https proxy multiple external ports to pods on http in deployment?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, docker-desktop

I'm trying to do a straight up thing that I would think is simple. I need to have https://localhost:44301, https://localhost:5002, https://localhost:5003 to be listened to in my k8s environment in docker desktop, and be proxied using a pfx file/password that I specify and have it forward by the port to pods listening on specific addresses (could be port 80, doesn't matter)

The documentation is mind numbingly complex for what looks like it should be straight forward. I can get the pods running, I can use kubectl port-forward and they work fine, but I can't figure out how to get ingress working with ha-proxy or nginx or anything else in a way that makes any sense.

Can someone do an ELI5 telling me how to turn this on? I'm on Windows 10 2004 with WSL2 and Docker experimental so I should have access to the ingress stuff they reference in the docs and make clear as mud.

Thanks!

Comment: Please check [this answer/guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59255445/how-can-i-access-nginx-ingress-on-my-local/59274163#59274163) and let me know if that helps you.

Comment: That's pretty close to what I was about to write up after spending a day on it.  The trick was not to use the nginx version of the nginx ingress and use the one from Google and things go more smoothly.

Comment: Please consider to upvote the original answer too. Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As discussed in the comments this is a community wiki answer:

---

I have managed to create Ingress resource in Kubernetes on Docker in Windows.

**Steps to reproduce**:

- Enable Hyper-V
- Install Docker for Windows and enable Kubernetes
- Connect kubectl
- Enable Ingress
- Create deployment
- Create service
- Create ingress resource
- Add host into local hosts file
- Test

#### Enable [Hyper-V](https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/quick-start/enable-hyper-v)

From Powershell with administrator access run below command:

`Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName  Microsoft-Hyper-V -All`

System could ask you to reboot your machine.

#### Install Docker for Windows and enable Kubernetes

Install Docker application with all the default options and enable Kubernetes

#### Connect kubectl

Install [kubectl](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-kubectl/#install-kubectl-on-windows) .

#### Enable Ingress

Run this commands:

```
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/master/deploy/static/mandatory.yaml
```

```
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/master/deploy/static/provider/cloud-generic.yaml
```

#### **Edit:** Make sure no other service is using port 80

Restart your machine. From a `cmd` prompt running as admin, do:
`net stop http`
Stop the listed services using `services.msc`

Use: `netstat -a -n -o -b` and check for other processes listening on port 80.

#### Create deployment

Below is simple deployment with pods that will reply to requests:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: hello
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: hello
      version: 2.0.0
  replicas: 3
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: hello
        version: 2.0.0
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: hello
        image: "gcr.io/google-samples/hello-app:2.0"
        env:
        - name: "PORT"
          value: "50001"
```

Apply it by running command:

`$ kubectl apply -f file_name.yaml`

#### Create service

For pods to be able for you to communicate with them you need to create a service.

Example below:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: hello-service
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: hello
    version: 2.0.0
  ports:
  - name: http
    protocol: TCP
    port: 80
    targetPort: 50001
```

Apply this service definition by running command:

`$ kubectl apply -f file_name.yaml`

#### Create Ingress resource

Below is simple Ingress resource using service created above:

```yaml
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: hello-ingress 
spec:
  rules:
  - host: kubernetes.docker.internal
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: hello-service 
          servicePort: http
```

Take a look at:

```yaml
spec:
  rules:
  - host: hello-test.internal
```

`hello-test.internal` will be used as the `hostname` to connect to your pods.

Apply your Ingress resource by invoking command:

`$ kubectl apply -f file_name.yaml`

#### Add host into local hosts file

I found this [Github link](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/1901)  that will allow you to connect to your Ingress resource by `hostname`.

To achieve that add a line `127.0.0.1 hello-test.internal` to your `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` file and save it. 
You will need Administrator privileges to do that.

**Edit:** The newest version of Docker Desktop for Windows already adds a hosts file entry:
`127.0.0.1 kubernetes.docker.internal`

#### Test

Display the information about Ingress resources by invoking command: 
`kubectl get ingress`

It should show:

```
NAME            HOSTS                 ADDRESS     PORTS   AGE
hello-ingress   hello-test.internal   localhost   80      6m2s
```

Now you can access your Ingress resource by opening your web browser and typing

`http://kubernetes.docker.internal/`

The browser should output:

```
Hello, world!
Version: 2.0.0
Hostname: hello-84d554cbdf-2lr76
```

`Hostname: hello-84d554cbdf-2lr76` is the name of the pod that replied.

If this solution is not working please check connections with the command: 
`netstat -a -n -o` 
(**with Administrator privileges**) if something is not using port 80.

---

Comment: Note this also works with WSL2 direct mostly without modification.