# Enable Ingress controller on Docker Desktop with WLS2

Tags: docker, kubernetes, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

Currently, I'm using Docker Desktop with **WSL2** integration. I found that **Docker Desktop** automatically had created a cluster for me. It means I don't have to install and use **Minikube** or **Kind** to create cluster.
The problem is that, how could I enable **Ingress Controller** if I use "built-in" cluster from Docker Desktop?
I tried to create an **Ingress** to check if this work or not, but as my guess, it didn't work.

The YAML file I created as follows:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: webapp
spec:
  minReadySeconds: 30
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: webapp
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: webapp
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: webapp
        image: nodejs-helloworld:v1

--- 

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: webapp-service

spec:
  selector: 
    app: webapp
  
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 3000
      nodePort: 30090 # only for NotPort > 30,000
    
  type: NodePort #ClusterIP inside cluster

---

apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress 
metadata:
  name: webapp-ingress
spec:
  defaultBackend:
    service:
      name: webapp-service
      port:
        number: 3000
  rules:
  - host: ingress.local
    http:
      paths:
      - path: / 
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name:  webapp-service
            port: 
              number: 3000
```

I tried to access *ingress.local/* but it was not successful. (I added ingress.local to point to 127.0.0.1 in host file. And the **webapp** worked fine at *kubernetes.docker.internal:30090* )

Could you please help me to know the root cause?
Thank you.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Finally I found the way to fix. I have to deploy ingress Nginx by command:

```
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/controller-v0.41.2/deploy/static/provider/cloud/deploy.yaml
```

(Follows the instruction at https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/#docker-for-mac. It works just fine for Docker for Windows)

Now I can access http://ingress.local successfully.

Comment: For troubleshooting issues with `ValidatingWebhookConfiguration`, see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61616203/nginx-ingress-controller-failed-calling-webhook

Comment: Thanks! This really helped me. I spent ages trying to get it working with minikube, to no avail, but following this for docker desktop for windows worked perfectly. Thanks again!

Comment: If you still get the nginx 404 error page when accessing your backend, check if you have the "annotations" part of your ingress deployment and if not, add annotations: kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx".

Comment: @AmelMahmuzić your comment is great! I was doing everything correctly as of the example in the question, but adding annotations: kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx" solved it, Thanks.

Comment: @Shadi that's awesome. Glad to hear it worked.

Comment: **Now** this is properly documented for [Docker for Desktop](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/#docker-desktop) and it simply says, following the [quickstart instructions](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/#quick-start), which basically boils down to either `kubectl apply -f` the provided, **matching** _YAML_ or using _helm_. Above link most likely won't work with recent K8s, see [compatibility](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/?tab=readme-ov-file#supported-versions-table), so do not take above link _blindly_.

Answer (score 21):

You have to install an ingress-nginx controller on your cluster, so that your nodes will have an opened port 80/443.

Using `helm` (v3 - see [documentation](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/#using-helm)):

```sh
helm install --namespace kube-system nginx ingress-nginx --repo https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx
```

Using `kubectl` (see [documentation](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/#provider-specific-steps)):

```sh
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/controller-v0.43.0/deploy/static/provider/cloud/deploy.yaml
```

Then manually adding your ingresses' hostnames to `/etc/hosts`:

```
127.0.0.1     ingress.local
127.0.0.1     my.other.service.local
# ...
```

Then if you make a request on http://ingress.local:

- the DNS resolution will route to your cluster node
- then the ingress controller will serve the request on port 80
- then ingress will route the request to the configured backend service
- and the service will route to an available pod

Answer (score 11):

The newest version of Docker Desktop for Windows already adds a hosts file entry:  `127.0.0.1 kubernetes.docker.internal`.

You had to do use [`kubernetes.docker.internal`](http://kubernetes.docker.internal/) URL as a hostname in Ingress definition if you want to point to `127.0.0.1`.  This should be in the docs on this page [kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/) but there is no Docker Desktop for Windows section there.
Your files should look like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: webapp-service
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: webapp
  ports:
  - name: http
    protocol: TCP
    port: 3000
    nodePort: 30090
```

Your Ingress file should look like this:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: webapp-ingress 
spec:
  rules:
  - host: kubernetes.docker.internal
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: webapp-service 
          servicePort: http
```

Then you are able to connect to app using `http://kubernetes.docker.internal/`.

Example you can see here: [wsl2-docker-for-desktop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60839510/docker-desktop-k8s-plus-https-proxy-multiple-external-ports-to-pods-on-http-in).

Comment: Thanks @Malgorzata, but it does still not work. "kubernetes.docker.internal refused to connect."

Comment: @tuq you have to install nginx-ingress, so that your cluster will listen on port 80

Answer (score 3):

I used the Docker-Desktop version to install the nginx-ingress controller
https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/#docker-desktop
[image: Installing Kubernetes Ingress Controller Docker Desktop Windows]

curl http://kubernetes.docker.internal/

[image]

Offcourse I've not installed any workload yet but the default ingress controller works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

With Kustomize you can simply use

```
helmCharts:
  - name: ingress-nginx
    releaseName: ingress-nginx
    repo: https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx
```

Answer (score 0):

This is just to point out that Amel Mahmuzićs comment is still valid with a recent (I used the ingress-nginx Helm Chart 4.4.2) ingress deployment.

I could not get this to work for far too long (I tried to follow the [Strapi fodadvisor example](https://strapi.io/blog/deploying-and-scaling-the-official-strapi-demo-app-foodadvisor-with-kubernetes) with Docker Desktop build in Kubernetes instead of minikube) and always received a 404 from the ingress.

However, after using this yaml with the added annotation

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: main-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: foodadvisor.backend
    http:
      paths:
        - path: /
          pathType: Prefix
          backend:
            service:
              name: foodadvisor-backend
              port:
                number: 1337
  - host: foodadvisor.client
    http:
      paths:
        - path: /
          pathType: Prefix
          backend:
            service:
              name: foodadvisor-frontend
              port:
                number: 3000
```

it worked immediately. The [K82 docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#deprecated-annotation) mention, that this annotation is deprecated.

Comment: Instead annotation it is better to add to spec section ingressClassName: nginx.