# Can't access application on localhost under Docker Desktop Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, docker-desktop

I have been running an application stack successfully on a server using the *k3s* Kubernetes implementation. I am now attempting to deploy it on my Windows PC in Docker Desktop. I get a **404 not found** when accessing the application on the localhost.

- I tried using 'localhost', '127.0.0.1' and
  'kubernetes.docker.internal' (the latter is assigned to 127.0.0.1 by
  Docker Desktop on installation) - none work.
- I have tried all these
  host names with ports 80, 8000, 443, 8443, etc. No luck.

I'm using *Traefik* as my ingress controller, with TLS switched on, certificates are issued by cert-manager. For the local deployment, I use the cert-manager *self-signed* option. I have also *removed* the TLS spec from my ingress, but it makes no difference.

Here is my ingress definition, using 'kubernetes.docker.internal' as host:

```
    apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
    kind: Ingress
    metadata:
      name: traefik-ingress
      annotations:
        kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "traefik"
        cert-manager.io/issuer: self-signed
    spec:
      tls:
        - secretName: s3a-tls-certificate-secret
          hosts:
            - kubernetes.docker.internal
      rules:
      - http:
          paths:
            - path: /
              pathType: Prefix
              backend:
                service:
                  name: s3a-frontend
                  port:
                    number: 80
```

- When I try http**s**://kubernetes.docker.internal (implied port 443), on first attempt, Chrome shows me the "unsafe self-signed certificate, press Advanced to continue" stuff, but when I do continue, I get 404 page not found.
- When I try plain http://kubernetes.docker.internal (implied port 80), I get Chrome ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE.
- When I remove the TLS stuff completely from the ingress, it does exactly the same as above for ports http and https.
- You'll see the spec/rules don't specify a specific host, i.e. the spec applies to *all* hosts. I've tried fixing it to host 'kubernetes.docker.internal', but as expected, it makes no difference.

The target service "s3a-frontend" is running on its exposed port 80: *I can access it* when hitting it directly on its node port, but *not via the ingress*.

EDIT:
The Traefik ingress controller comes with k3s, but I installed it manually in Docker Desktop. When I attach to the traefik pod, I can see a request being logged when I access https://kubernetes.docker.internal, here are the logs. You can see the cluster health checks ("ping@internal"), but also my request for root ("/") and then Chrome's request for favicon, neither of which return a response code.

```
10.1.0.1     - - [05/Nov/2021:16:36:23 +0000] "GET /ping HTTP/1.1" 200 2 "-" "-" 2141 "ping@internal" "-" 0ms
192.168.65.3 - - [05/Nov/2021:16:36:24 +0000] "GET / HTTP/2.0" - - "-" "-" 2142 "-" "-" 0ms
10.1.0.1     - - [05/Nov/2021:16:36:24 +0000] "GET /ping HTTP/1.1" 200 2 "-" "-" 2143 "ping@internal" "-" 0ms
192.168.65.3 - - [05/Nov/2021:16:36:24 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/2.0" - - "-" "-" 2144 "-" "-" 0ms
```

/END EDIT

I have done a lot of research, including on the possibility that something else is hogging ports 80/443. netstat says that *Docker itself* is listening on those ports: how can I claim those ports if Docker itself is using it, or is this a red herring?

**System**

- Windows 10 Pro, 10.0.19043
- WSL2
- Docker Desktop reports engine v20.10.8

Comment: k3s comes bundled with the traefik ingress controller. kubernetes on docker-desktop does not. see this question for more information and a solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65193758/enable-ingress-controller-on-docker-desktop-with-wls2

Comment: Did solution provided in comment above help you?

Comment: I installed Traefik manually. I'll update my question with more details.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't get this working on Docker Desktop. I switched to [Rancher Desktop](https://rancherdesktop.io/) and it worked.

Comment: So, I assume you abandoned previous configuration and you don't need help with that anymore. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately. I've switched to Rancher Desktop.