# Does Minikube with Docker Driver supports Ingress on Mac or Windows?

Tags: macos, kubernetes-ingress, minikube, nginx-ingress

Does Minikube with Docker Driver supports Ingress on Mac or Windows?

I followed as it is steps listed in the [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/ingress-minikube/).

But, it's not working

I tried `minikube tunnel` as well, but it's not working. Can someone help me with this please?

Answer (score 0):

Ingress has some conflicts to work with Docker on Windows10 .So the workaround here can be installing Virtualbox.

**On Windows**:

1.Install [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads)

2.Uncheck the Virtual Machine Platform and Windows Hypervisor Platform options from Control Panel -> Programs -> Turn Windows Features on and off (under Programs and Features) and then click ok. Restart your computer if prompted to.

3.Now, execute the following commands in a new cmd

```
minikube delete
minikube start --driver=virtualbox
```

if `minikube start --driver=virtualbox` doesn't work, then use `minikube start --driver=virtualbox --no-vtx-check`.

Also checkout the [Github](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/7332) issue and stackoverflow [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65193758/enable-ingress-controller-on-docker-desktop-with-wls2) for more information.

Comment: Tanks Fariya for the answer. But I need the Ingress to work with Docker driver, not with virtualbox

Comment: I have updated the answer with my findings.Let me know if it helps.

Comment: So, you mean to say Ingress doesn't work with Docker Driver on Minikube @Fariya?

Comment: Yes, According to [documentation](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/drivers/docker/).The ingress, and ingress-dns addons are currently only supported on Linux.