# Issue with install ingress-nginx on Window (Not minikube)

Tags: docker, nginx, kubernetes, nginx-ingress

I'm using Window and learning Kubernetes, I'm trying to install ingress-nginx by running this command 
`kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/controller-v0.35.0/deploy/static/provider/cloud/deploy.yaml`.
It didn't work at 1st, so I copied the yaml file locally and run "kubectl apply -f" on that local file but then I got this

`unable to recognize "ingress.yaml": Get https://kubernetes.docker.internal:6443/api?timeout=32s: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:6443: connectex: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.`

Please help me (I don't use minikube)

Comment: Hi, have you seen this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59255445/how-can-i-access-nginx-ingress-on-my-local

Answer (score 0):

This is the issue with `kubectl` itself that doesn't see your `~/.kube/config`.
Most probably you will see nothing if run

```
kubectl config view
apiVersion: v1
clusters: []
contexts: []
current-context: ""
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users: []
```

Make sure [KUBECONFIG](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/organize-cluster-access-kubeconfig/) looks to your config file(`~/.kube/config`)

You mat also want to visit [Trouble installing applications in Kubernetes](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/1651) github issue for more information